# Websphere AS conflicts between Two eclipse workspaces

Tags: java, websphere, myeclipse

I am new to Websphere. Right now, I am setting up workspace for two projects in separate eclipse workspaces in MyEclipseBlue 2016 using Websphere 8.5 Application Server. Profiles are configured separately for those projects.

Need to work with both applications at the same time since one application depends on the other. When I deploy the applications separately by opening any one workspace, server starts without any errors. But when both workspaces are open, starting/stopping a server in one workspace, makes the server in other workspace to does the same and exception occurs when server starts.

I don't know how this occurs, How both the servers in separate eclipse workspaces are integrated?

Websphere variables under Environment in Admin console are different for both projects since they are configured with different profiles. But When deploying both the applications at the same time, Websphere variables specific to any one of the profiles gets applied for both the projects.

Unable to find the way to deploy these two projects with different websphere profiles at the same time.

Please advise.

Comment: It looks like, although you have 2 separate profiles, your both Eclipse workspaces point to the same profile. Other reason could be that both profiles use the same ports (but I'm counting more on the first issue). So make sure that servers configured in Eclipse are pointing to different profiles.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you have an installation of WAS 8.5, with two profiles, say AppSvr01 and AppSvr02, and two eclipse workspaces, say ws1 and ws2, and you are using the WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse to manage the servers?  And ws1 workspace is configured in WDT to use WAS profile AppSvr01 and ws2 workspace is configured to use WAS profile AppSvr02?  If the interaction you describe is happening, some possibilities are 1) WDT is using the same WAS profile in both ws1 and ws2 workspaces, 2) the WAS profiles AppSvr01 and AppSvr02 have conflicting port assignments, or 3) WDT is not configured to use unique ports to communicate with the server.  #1 is easy to check in the WDT Server editor settings.  #2 shouldn't be the case as you stated the port assignments are unique to the profiles.  #3 is also easily checked in the WDT Server editor. Examine the "Server connection types and admin ports" section for both profiles and verify they're unique to each workspace, if not, override them.  If they are unique, run each workspace by itself, have WDT start the server and examine the logs to see what profile the workspace is actually starting and on what ports.

Answer (score 0):

The WebSphere connectors in MyEclipse are somewhat intelligent in that they can detect if the server is running or not. When you start WebSphere in one workspace, the other will detect that it is started and show "running" status. Similarly if the server is stopped. Although you have separate profiles, are they using the same ports? If so, change the port numbers. You can see the port numbers quickly by double clicking the connector in the Servers view (which brings up a configuration editor) though you'll have to change them through the WebClipse profile manager.

Alternatively, use a single workspace for both projects, since one depends on the other, and use a single profile. You haven't said why you need to use separate profiles and workspaces (not sure how the dependency works in that case).